# Erro de dois Form em uma pagina asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Estou com um problema em relação ao form do asp.net . Minha master page possui um form, e a pagina filha também possui um form que passa algumas ações do javascript para adicionar um produto ao carrinho.
Só que quando eu vou clicar qualquer botão que esteja com essa master page, ele automaticamente adiciona um produto ao carrinho.

Meu professor disse que não pode ter form dentro de form.

Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por isso ou se tem alguma solução para isso.
Obrigado

Comment: Olá, de fato não faz sentido ter um form dentro de form. Você poderia incluir o código para melhor análise?

Comment: Coloque o código da sua pagina, agora não pode ter um form dentro do outro, mas, pode ter quantos forms quiser dentro de uma pagina, não sendo dentro um do outro normal.